# Как сделать нужную область видимости?

Tags: javascript, наследование, замыкания

В библиотеке Jquery, заметна одна особенность, что фрагмент кода берется в анонимную переменную и передается в качестве аргумента функции.

```
$(function(){ ///... })
```

Вопрос состоит в том... Как они это сделали? Я сделал следующий фрагмент:

```
function Lib(func){
  var a = 12;
  return func();
}

Lib(function(){ console.log(a); });
```

Но переменная `a` не в области видимости... Как сделать так, чтобы вызванная анонимная функция получила переменную `a` и вообще все методы и свойства функции `Lib`. Хотелось создать отельный набор функций (чтобы они были доступны только внутри `Lib`

```
 Lib(function(){ console.log(a); });
```

Я понимаю, что есть другой вариант реализации, но интересует именно в стиле jQuery.

Comment: в данном примере ничего не передается: `$(function(){ ///... })` можете привести более развернутый пример?

Comment: определите переменную как глобальную: `a = 12;` без "var".

Comment: @Sergiks, тогда уж лучше параметром передать `func(a)` и `Lib(function(a){ ...`

Comment: @Grundy, то что предложил Sergiks, меня устраивает, однако, я слышал, что это является плохим тоном... А насчет версии Вашей, хотел сказать, что тут есть одно НО. У меня в планах не один элемент переменная, которую хотел сделать глобальной и брать их в объекты ... не хотелось бы. Я еще надеюсь, что есть хороший способ реализовать то что мне хотелось. Но все равно спасибо за ответы!

Comment: @АлексейФурсов, вы просто так и не раскрыли, **что именно** вы хотите получить

Comment: если вы имели ввиду использование `$` внутри функций при работе с jQuery - то тут используется глобальная переменная

Answer (score 1):

```
function Lib(func){
  var a = 12;
  return func(a);
}

Lib(function(a){ console.log(a); });
```